# Laravel get many to many polymorphic results

Tags: php, laravel, polymorphism, many-to-many

For example, I have two models:

Task Model:

```
public function payments()
{
    return $this->morphedByMany(Payment::class, 'taskable');
}
```

Payment Model:

```
public function tasks()
{
    return $this->morphToMany(Task::class, 'taskable');
}
```

So each `Payment` can have many `Tasks`. Also, each `Subscription` can have many `Tasks`. And a bunch of other models. That's why I'm using a `Many-to-Many Polymorphic` relation for this.

I wish to display `all` tasks for a given model, without having to use foreach loops. So for example:

```
auth()->user()->payments()->tasks
```

But this doesn't work. Is there an elegant way to resolve this?

Comment: Do u have  user_id in payments table?

Comment: I do, and I was looking for hasManyThrough but I don't think that will work for this?

Comment: What's the output of payments()?  I believe that if you call it as a method it will output the builder and if you call it as a property it will output a collection.  So ... I don't think you could call ->tasks on either of those.  Maybe something like $user->payments->first()->tasks or whatever to get the model/object.

Comment: True, that doesn't work indeed. I am going to switch things around anyway since only one task should belong to only one payment, subscription, and so on. So my design is off anyway. Thanks for thinking along :)